# Error NU1107 Version conflict detected for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget, nuget-package

I get the following error:

> *Error NU1107 Version conflict detected for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.*
>
> *Install/reference Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData 2.4.1.1 directly to project MyProject.Android to resolve this issue.*
>
> *MyProject.Android -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads 121.2.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite 121.2.0 ->
> Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime 2.7.1.3 ->
> Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData (>= 2.4.1.1)*
>
> *MyProject.Android -> Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2515 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData (>= 2.3.1.1 && < 2.4.0).*

Which packages should I upgrade or downgrade in order to achieve compatibility?

Comment: Have you tried doing explicitly what the error messaged says? That is referencing Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData version 2.4.1.1 in your Android .csproj ?

Comment: No, I haven't. How do I do this? And what's actually the point? Does this mean that it is possible to have two different versions of a package installed and reference whichever you wish from a certain project?

Comment: You can manage your packages directly from visual studio with the [Package manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio) OR you can find your *.csproj files within your specifc project folders in your solution to do it manually. It is not possible to have 2 different versions of the same package and this is the root of your current problem. Since you do not have an explicitly reference of Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData, you have 2 other packages that are both implicitly referencing 2 different versions of that package.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads 121.2.0 requires Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData >= 2.4.1.1. At the same time Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2515 requires Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData >= 2.3.1.1 && < 2.4.0. If I reference Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData version 2.4.1.1 in the Android .csproj wouldn't this still cause a conflict with the Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2515 package?

Comment: I am guessing that depends on how Xamarin.Forms responds to that out of scope version of Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData. Maybe adding 2.4.1.1 just works magically. But you are probably right in assuming that that might cause a different error. You will then have to update in turn your Xamarin.Forms package version as well to match. And is that doesn't work, instead you might have to downgrade your version of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads instead.

Comment: In all cases, this error message usually let's you know exactly what package is causing the error, and which package and version you need to explicitly reference in order to resolve the conflict. Just like the error message you posted initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a new project to test the packages you mentioned. And I found two solutions:

Just use the following package in your project's android part:

- **Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser version 1.4.0.1**
- **Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData version 2.4.1.1**
- **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads version 121.2.0**
- **Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.2515**

This solution just adds the reference to the project's android part according to the error messages. And the project will build successfully even though there are still some warnings about the package.

**The second solution:**

- **use the Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.2545**
- **and the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads version  120.4.0**

The Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads version 120.4.0 is the newest version which is compatible with the Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.3.0.6 && < 1.4.0). If you use the two packages above, there will not be any warnings or errors about the reference.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.2515 and Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser version 1.4.0.1 are not compatible.
Anyway, I finally found a solution. I updated Xamarin.AndroidX.Core to the latest version and this allowed me to update Xamarin.Forms to the latest version while using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads 120.4.0.

The versions of Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser and Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData I think were handled automatically by the package manager when installing the updates. So basically your second solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should upgrade to Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2545. It [allows for LiveData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms#dependencies-body-tab) to be high enough. It's a minor upgrade for XF, so it shouldn't cause you any issues to upgrade.

If for whatever reason you can't upgrade Xamarin Forms, you'll need to downgrade GooglePlayServices.Ads to a version that allows for the lower Work.Runtime version which in turn allows for the lower LiveData version.

Comment: I had already tried to. I'm getting these errors when trying to upgrade: ` Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyProject.Android'. 
Error NU1107 Version conflict detected for Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser. Install/reference Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser 1.4.0.1 directly to project MyProject.Android to resolve this issue.
MyProject.Android -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads 121.2.0 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.4.0.1) 
MyProject.Android -> Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2545 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.3.0.6 && < 1.4.0).`